# didSelectRowAtIndexPath returns wrong row index inconsistently

Tags: ios, swift2, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table view with rows, and when clicking on the row, sometimes it returns the row that is up one position from the one I clicked. The relevant code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    currentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!

    //.... cell modifications

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // this is to make at least one empty row
    if (meeting.attendees.isEmpty) {
        return 1
    } else {
        if section == 0 {
            return requiredParticipants.count }
        else {
            return optionalParticipants.count }
    }
}
```

**What did I do to address the issue:**

**1.** checked the consistency of arrays with the numberOfRows function (it's correct, the number is right)

**2.** checked the height of the cell - suspected the upper cell to overlap somehow the bottom cell - also not the case

**3.** refactored cellForRow to use dequeReusableCell (was not used initially) - suspected the memory issue, also did not help.

What happens: when you click, the cell that is clicked is highlighted with the green light, and approx. 50% of the time, the cell one position up from the one you click gets highlighted. The issue is also inconsistent, meaning that half of the time the right one is highlighted.

Comment: index start from the 0

Comment: @Async- Are you mutating the array I mean modifying the array in background when cell gets tapped ???

Comment: no, this was my initial concern, the array is never changed

Comment: @Gamex in both cases actually: array is 0 index based, and indexPath.row starts with a 0, so this should not be the issue

Comment: Do you change manually the size of the cell at a moment ?

Comment: @AnthonyRoani no, I do not

Comment: The only things I modify in cell are label text, and label color.

Comment: I suppose you have removed the default selection highlight, can you please enable it again ? Comment the `didSelect...()` method entirely, and check if the selected cell is now correctly highlighted. I suspect a problem in the `didSelect` method. And how many sections do you have ?

Comment: @AnthonyRoani just commented out everything except highlighting, issue is still there..

Comment: I have only 2 sections, the issue is not in the didSelect, because highlighting happens on the wrong cell, even when everything else is removed

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?